# SignalR bare WebSocket. How to detect that client lost internet connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, websocket, signalr

I have an Asp.Net Core 6 Web Api project. I add SignalR middleware:

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);
});
```

I add a handler:

```
app.MapConnectionHandler<SocialWeatherConnectionHandler>("/weather");
```

When I turn off client internet connection I don't get any notifications/exceptions. How I can detect when the client got disconnected?

Comment: You can't detect this reliably. Use combination of pings and timeouts.

Comment: @freakish I will be happy if I find a way to do it by Asp.Net/SignalR infrastructure but it seems it's impossbile.

Comment: I add an issue on the Asp.Net SignalR repository: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/48147

Answer (score 1):

I check all the document about asp.net signalr [Physical connection disconnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#signalr-connections-transport-connections-and-physical-connections) and [ASP.NET Core SignalR configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=dotnet).

I think we should use `ClientTimeoutInterval` and `KeepAliveInterval` to detect the client side lose internet connection.

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(options =>
{
    options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);
    options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
});
```

And also need to set `serverTimeoutInMilliseconds` in client side.

```
connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 2000;
```

*The recommended ServerTimeout or serverTimeoutInMilliseconds value is double the KeepAliveInterval value*

Then you can get error message in onclose event.

```
connection.onclose((error) => {
    console.log("Disconnected");
    console.log(`Something went wrong: ${error}`);
});
```

**After testing, Although the ping timeout is shortened to 1 second, it is still impossible to detect the disconnection of the network immediately in real time.**

From the screenshot below, the browser does not receive the ping message from the server, and the onclose event will be triggered after about 20 seconds.

[image]

Comment: It is impossible to detect such event reliably. Regardless of whether this is signalr or any other protocol over unreliable link. Because this problem is a variant [two generals problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem). And so yes, the best we can do is depend on a combination of pings and timeouts.

Comment: Yes, I very much agree with your point of view. My original intention of testing this demo is to see if I can detect network disconnection faster. However, it took about 10-20s to find the internet disconnection.

Answer (score 1):

According to MS engineer answer (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/48147):
ConnectionHandlers are at a layer beneath SignalR. In other words, any SignalR feature (e.g. AddSignalR) will not apply to ConnectionHandler usage. So there is no built in possibility to track whether a client lost internet connection or not if we use bare WebSocket by ConnectionHandlers.