# Signal R Kestrel disconnect event

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

there is this article, but I cannot comment or add anything there:
76024866/signalr-hub-ondisconnectedasync-sometimes-takes-thirty-seconds-to-fire-but-ot

My signalR relies heavely on the disconenct event.

When i close my Xamarin or WPF apps, it usually fires the disconnect very fast.

BUT: when I just disable my WIFI, for some reason it does not fire the event for many minutes. I know this since I have the client ID in the DB and dictionary object.

The client connection object state is disconnected !!

In the article above it states that I  should add the

options.ServerTimeout,

but in my Net core 7 with all updates, I can only find these parameters, but not the ServerTimeout

```
        hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        hubOptions.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
```

Can anyone please help me understand, why it takes up to 10 minutes, until the server releases the disconnection event (I have database and dictionary sanatize events for the device, which shows that the server has not processed the disconnect event)

Comment: You refer to an article,  but you didn't add a link to it. Please edit the question to add the link.

Comment: thanx for the suggestion: I added it on top, but the domain was left out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76024866/signalr-hub-ondisconnectedasync-sometimes-takes-thirty-seconds-to-fire-but-ot

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar problem. After my PC was disconnected from the network, the ondisconnectedasync method was not triggered in time after losing the network connection.

Configuration parameters in your code should eventually detect disconnected behavior, but it will take a long time.

> [ConnectionHandlers are at a layer beneath SignalR. In other words, any SignalR feature (e.g. AddSignalR) will not apply to ConnectionHandler usage.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76215570/7687666)