# ASP.NET Core WebSocket. Detect when WebSocket client lost intenet connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, websocket

I use Asp.Net Core WebSockets according to this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0. When WebSocket client lost internet connection server get notification after about 20 minutes. Documentation says: "have the client use a timer to send a ping message every X seconds". But there is no possibility to track ping/pong messages. It's deep inside ManagedWebSocket: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet/blob/eb24b2bf58a85e34199f319b60c30551e65984c5/src/runtime/src/libraries/System.Net.WebSockets/src/System/Net/WebSockets/ManagedWebSocket.cs#L735. How can I detect that my WebSocket client lost internet connection?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/29309

Comment: You have the client to actively send a 'heartbeat' message every minute or so and have the server do the same. When either ends didn't receive a heartbeat message for over 2 minutes, consider the connection dead. But you're on your own here. Nothing in the framework will help you. You have to implement that mechanism on either or both ends.

Comment: Seems no solution for this requirement, [you can check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76215570/7687666).

Answer (score 1):

Detect when a WebSocket client loses its internet connection:

Heartbeat Messages: Instead of relying on the ping/pong mechanism, you can implement a heartbeat system using custom messages. Both the client and server can periodically exchange these heartbeat messages. If the server doesn't receive a heartbeat message within a specified timeframe, it can assume that the client has lost its connection.

Connection Timeout: In addition to the heartbeat messages, you can implement a connection timeout mechanism on the server side. Set a maximum duration that a client should send messages within. If the server doesn't receive any messages from the client within that timeframe, it can consider the client's connection as lost.

Network-Level Monitoring: You can utilize network-level monitoring tools to detect network disruptions or failures. This approach involves monitoring network connectivity on the server-side independently from the WebSocket protocol. You can implement network monitoring techniques such as ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol) pings or periodic HTTP requests to check if the client is still reachable.

Keep-Alive Headers: Configure keep-alive headers on the server side to help detect client disconnections. By setting appropriate keep-alive intervals, the server can monitor the responsiveness of the client. If the server doesn't receive a response within the specified interval, it can assume the client has disconnected.

Custom SignalR Handlers: If you're using SignalR, which is built on top of WebSockets, you can leverage custom SignalR handlers to detect client disconnections. SignalR provides events such as OnDisconnectedAsync, which you can use to handle the disconnection and execute specific actions.